# Fixed Header Issue When Scrolling To Anchor From External Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I recently repurposed a template for http://c42d.com, a portfolio website I'm building for a company called C42D.  My issue concerns the scrolling functionality of the navigation system.

It works properly on the homepage.  When you click any link in the nav at the top, it scrolls right to that section on the page perfectly, and it takes into consideration the height of the fixed header.  The following Javascript is responsible for this functionality:

```
        /** Hash Scroll */
        /** Portfolio Filter */
        $( '#navbar-spy' ).off( 'click' ).on( 'click', 'a', function( e ) {         

            if(!$( this ).attr( 'href' ).match(/^#/)) return;
            e.preventDefault();

            var elmHash = $( this ).attr( 'href' );
            var elmOffsetTop = Math.ceil( $( this.hash ).offset().top );
            var windowOffsetTop = Math.ceil( $(window).scrollTop() );

            if( elmOffsetTop != 0 ) {
                elmOffsetTop = elmOffsetTop - 84;
                if( windowOffsetTop == 0 ) {
                    elmOffsetTop = elmOffsetTop - 0;
                }
            }

            //console.log( $( this ).attr( 'href' ) );              
            $( 'html:not(:animated), body:not(:animated)' ).animate({ scrollTop: elmOffsetTop }, 1100 );                                              

        });
```

Unfortunately, when you navigate to any interior page on the site (http://c42d.com/termsandconditions, for example) and click a link in the nav, it brings you right to the proper anchor on the homepage, but doesn't take into consideration the height of the fixed header, and the title becomes partly obscured.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!
Zan

Comment: The links don't fire any javascript, so there would be no way to run any of your code that calculated the height of the top nav.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is on page load, detect the hash if any, and if there is, then run that same animation code to go to that.